# Associate an external application url to jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to link or associate an external application url to jenkins job build.
So for every builds, this link or url should be available at the left side and any user can simply click on it to launch the external application.

So far I explored the following plugins for this:

1. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Associated+Files+Plugin -  this associates a file or directory to the build , something similar to the html publisher plugin... not a url
2. https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/DocLinks+Plugin - similar to above , associate a doc from the build artifact directories
3. https://wiki.jenkins.io/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=52298023 - this Side bar link plugin can associate a external link to the jenkin project, but not to every builds

for me the external link which I am trying to associate to the build , dynamically changes for each build , basically some of the query parameter in the external link, so it's critical to associate it to every builds for tracking and other purposes . ex: the external link will be a like a small web app 
http:hostnamexxx:port/somepage?para1=xxx&para2=yyyy

Please let me know if there is any plugin for this specific purpose or any other ideas

Answer (score 1):

This would be the [Anchor Chain](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AnchorChain+plugin) plugin. I've played around with it a bit:

- The docs state that the icon can be omitted. Then however you need to insert a `tab` character after the URL.
- When inserting a link to an icon, it is always relative to Jenkins base URL.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan Hanke , I came across this earlier , didn't spend time on it as it reads the link from a file which has to be in the directory.. should the link in the file be a final one ? I meant can we update some query parameter in the link dynamically for each build like in my case ? as the link is going be a dynamic one for each build for me , mainly the query parameter in the link changes based on some build parameter i pass to jenkin build .